How many times can I go to the US in a year?
I'm thinking of going to the US this summer from June to September with an Visa Waiver Program for 3 months. And again for Christmas for 2 months, middle of December to middle of February.with Visa Waiver Program
Can I do this

ESTA is an automated system that determines the eligibility of visitors to travel to the United States under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP). There is no such thing as an ESTA visa

we in sweden has esta visa to us. its are a digital visa. that we can get esta visa from the computer. is this a scam. saw this on a website

Apply through the official website to avoid any possibility of scams. My point was simply that referring to an ESTA as an ‘ESTA visa’ is incorrect - an ESTA is an electronic authorisation to travel to the US, not a visa. See What is the US visa waiver program and what is an ESTA

In the US, ESTA is not was is considered "a visa", although in essence it serves a similar function.

@Traveller For all practical purposes the US ESTA system is exactly the same as the e-visa systems used by many other countries. Even if the US authorities for legal reasons have decided to not call the ESTA system a visa, it still is, at least in the meaning the word 'visa' is used everywhere else in the world.

I changed my question now.

You’re really on the edge (and probably slightly over) here: 3 months in, 2.5 months out, 2 months in. This will depend a lot on your circumstances (what you do back home). The very first questions that will come to the mind of the officer is “how can you afford to stay away for 5 months out of 7?” and “if you can stay away for so long, what incentive do you have to go back rather than overstaying in the US or just doing visa runs every 3 months?”.
